# J2EE Remote Enterprise Java Beans and Hibernate Annotated Classes

Tags: hibernate, annotations, ejb

I'm currently setting up a new application environment with all new J2EE-Technologies (EJB, Hibernate) in NetBeans 7.3.1 and glassfish 4.0 as an application server.
I'm going to install a core module (user management framework) as a remote enterprise bean which uses hibernate to persist all entities (such as users).
These entity classes heavily uses hibernate annotations.

Now, I want to add a Web-Frontend (JSF) and query some data from the core module. For example, I want to retrieve a list of all users from the core module.
But if I use the entity classes from above for the communication, all hibernate libraries must also be included to the web-frontend because these classes are annotated.

Is there any way to avoid this? I want to hide everything about persistance from the web frontend.

Comment: The annotations are not the problem. The problem is the hibernate proxies and collections contained in the entities. What's the problem in having hibernate jars in the webapp classpath?

Comment: I want to use some different version of hibernate in the webapp which are incompatible.

Comment: Then you might use web services and marshall/unmarshall to/from XML or JSON. Or you could transform all your entities to DTOs. Or you could standardize on one Hibernate version.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. 
Allthough, I couldn't find a satisfying method.